# Async Azure File Storage - Upload Tasks Wait For Other Tasks

Tags: c#, azure, async-await, file-storage

I have this code that runs a delegate asynchronously:

```
public delegate void FileHandler(string path);
....
FileHandler fileHandler = HandleFile;
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    string filePath = file.FullName;
    if (IO.FileAvailable(filePath))
    {
        fileHandler.BeginInvoke(filePath, null, null); // i call EndInvoke later
    }
}
```

Here is the delegate, that just uploads stuff into Azure File Storage:

```
private static void HandleFile(string path)
{
    AzureStorage.Instance.UploadFile("some-key", path);
}
```

Also, this is the Upload functions:

```
public async Task UploadFileAsync(string storageKey, string filePath)
{
    CloudFile loc = Navigate(storageKey);
    await TransferManager.UploadAsync(filePath, loc);
}

public void UploadFile(string storageKey, string filePath)
{
    Task uploadTask = UploadFileAsync(storageKey, filePath);
    Console.WriteLine("Will wait for " + storageKey + " path: " + filePath + " with thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    uploadTask.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine(">>> Done waiting for " + storageKey + " path: " + filePath);
    uploadTask.Dispose();
}
```

Here is my output:

```
Will wait for /bills/test/SomePdfName_1.pdf path: C:\test\SomePdfName_1.pdf with thread: 4
Will wait for /bills/test/SomePdfName_6.pdf path: C:\test\SomePdfName_6.pdf with thread: 7
Will wait for /bills/test/SomePdfName_10.pdf path: C:\test\SomePdfName_10.pdf with thread: 5
Will wait for /bills/test/SomePdfName_5.pdf path: C:\test\SomePdfName_5.pdf with thread: 9
Will wait for /bills/test/SomePdfName_3.pdf path: C:\test\SomePdfName_3.pdf with thread: 8
Will wait for /bills/test/SomePdfName_7.pdf path: C:\test\SomePdfName_7.pdf with thread: 11
Will wait for /bills/test/SomePdfName_4.pdf path: C:\test\SomePdfName_4.pdf with thread: 10
Will wait for /bills/test/SomePdfName_2.pdf path: C:\test\SomePdfName_2.pdf with thread: 6
Will wait for /bills/test/SomePdfName_8.pdf path: C:\test\SomePdfName_8.pdf with thread: 12
Will wait for /bills/test/SomePdfName_9.pdf path: C:\test\SomePdfName_9.pdf with thread: 13
.... 10 seconds later
>>> Done waiting for /bills/test/SomePdfName_9.pdf path: C:\test\SomePdfName_9.pdf
>>> Done waiting for /bills/test/SomePdfName_10.pdf path: C:\test\SomePdfName_10.pdf
>>> Done waiting for /bills/test/SomePdfName_1.pdf path: C:\test\SomePdfName_1.pdf
>>> Done waiting for /bills/test/SomePdfName_7.pdf path: C:\test\SomePdfName_7.pdf
>>> Done waiting for /bills/test/SomePdfName_2.pdf path: C:\test\SomePdfName_2.pdf
>>> Done waiting for /bills/test/SomePdfName_5.pdf path: C:\test\SomePdfName_5.pdf
>>> Done waiting for /bills/test/SomePdfName_6.pdf path: C:\test\SomePdfName_6.pdf
>>> Done waiting for /bills/test/SomePdfName_8.pdf path: C:\test\SomePdfName_8.pdf
>>> Done waiting for /bills/test/SomePdfName_3.pdf path: C:\test\SomePdfName_3.pdf
>>> Done waiting for /bills/test/SomePdfName_4.pdf path: C:\test\SomePdfName_4.pdf
```

As you see, all 10 tasks have to enter into Wait first, before any of the upload tasks finish? **My question why is that**? This is the same either with 5, 10, 100 or 1000 files.

Comment: In my opinion, this is related with thread pool size. Since the 
both BeginInvoke and await method will use thread pool's thread. The default size of the thread pool for a process depends on several factors, such as the size of the virtual address space.  The number of the threads exceed the current thread pool's thread. It doesn't immediately create new threads in all situations.It will create one thread every 0.5 seconds if there are outstanding tasks, up to the maximum number of threads.  So there are not enough threads to execute the await TransferManager.UploadAsync method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you see, all 10 tasks have to enter into Wait first, before any of the upload tasks finish? My question why is that? This is the same either with 5, 10, 100 or 1000 files.

In my opinion, I think this operation should divided into two cases.

First one. The file you upload doesn't exceed the thread pool number.

Since each of the BeginInvoke operations will choose one thread in the thread pool to execute the UploadFile method(All of the operation is async) and await TransferManager.UploadAsync will takes a lot of time to upload the file, so you will find, it looks like wait all the task to finish then start uploading.

In fact one thread will not affect another thread, just the thread is execute very fast.

Second, if the application use the thread number exceed the current thread pool number.

The default size of the thread pool for a process depends on several factors, such as the size of the virtual address space. The number of the threads exceed the current thread pool's thread. It doesn't immediately create new threads in all situations.It will create one thread every 0.5 seconds if there are outstanding tasks, up to the maximum number of threads.

So you will find the application firstly create enough thread to run the UploadFile looks like it wait first.In my opinion, there are not enough threads to execute the await TransferManager.UploadAsync method(this will get another thread from the thread pool to run it). Since the running upload thread has high priority than the await TransferManager.UploadAsync thread. So the computer will firstly create the new thread to run the UploadFile method. If all the UploadFile method run completely, then it will assign another thread to run the TransferManager.UploadAsync method.

If you want to your application doesn't wait all the task, you could try to use Parallel class.

More details, you could refer to this codes:

```
        Parallel.ForEach(dirInfo.GetFiles(), new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 108 }, (file) =>
        {
            string filePath = file.FullName;

            Console.WriteLine("start BeginInvoke for file: " + file + " with thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            fileHandler.Invoke(filePath); // i call EndInvoke later

            Console.WriteLine("end BeginInvoke for file: " + file + " with thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        });
```